# Combining lines of code

Tags: batch-file

How can i combine in my bat file

```
set FILESPATH1=C:\Temp\Test
set FILESPATH2=C:\Temp\Test\Bas
set FILESPATH3=C:\Temp\Test\Dennis
```

To one single line of code

Answer (score 3):

```
set "FILESPATH1=C:\Temp\Test"&set "FILESPATH2=C:\Temp\Test\Bas"&set "FILESPATH3=C:\Temp\Test\Dennis"
```

`&` separates commands; the quotes are not compulsory, but ensure that the value assigned to the variable doesn't contain invisible trailing spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want: you can use `&&` or `&` between the three commands.
`&&` executes the command(s) on its right if the command(s) on its left succeeded but `&` will execute the command(s) on its right even if the command(s) on its left failed (see [this link](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/condexec.php)).
In your case it doesn't really matter which one you use:

```
set "FILESPATH1=C:\Temp\Test" & set "FILESPATH2=C:\Temp\Test\Bas" & set "FILESPATH3=C:\Temp\Test\Dennis"
```